# Icon not displaying in barebones Firefox Addon

Tags: firefox-addon

I'm out of ideas. The physical button is there and works but the icons do not display. The icon-*.png files all exist in the root directory and I have the following specified:

index.js:

```
var self = require('sdk/self');

var buttons = require('sdk/ui/button/action');
var tabs = require("sdk/tabs");

var button = buttons.ActionButton({
id: "main-button",
    label: "Click to save for it!",
    // icon: "./icon-64.png",
    icon: {
        "16": "./icon-16.png",
        "32": "./icon-32.png",
        "64": "./icon-64.png"
    },
    onClick: handleClick
});

function handleClick(state) {
    tabs.open("https://www.mozilla.org/");
}
```

package.json:

```
{
    "title": "Test Addon",
    "name": "test-firefox",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "Test description",
    "main": "index",
    "author": "Test",
    "engines": {
        "firefox": ">=29.0",
        "fennec": ">=29.0"
    },
    "license": "GPL-3.0",
    "icon64": "icon-64.png",
    "icon": "icon-32.png"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer is simply that icons must go in data, same for any "lib" scripts. They are then specified based on the root of the data folder, and not the root project folder.